# Error accessing Gio.Gsettings on application made in quickly

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly, gsettings

I am trying to develop an application using the quickly/pygtk stack. I got my Gsettings schemas all set up in ~/app-name-here/data/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.app-name-here.gschema.xml correctly and I am able to access it just fine in my preferences dialog window that is located in ~/app-name-here/app-name-here/PreferencesDialog.py via

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
settings = Gio.Settings("net.launchpad.app-name-here")
settings.get_boolean('notify')
settings.set_boolean('notify', True)
```

but when I try to check the value of one of my settings in a file located in ~/app-name-here/bin/Daemon.py that I use as a script to run in the background and send notifications by a similar method of

```
from gi.repository import Gio
settings = Gio.Settings("net.launchpad.app-name-here")
settings.get_boolean('notify')
```

it fails at the line that says

```
settings = Gio.Settings("net.launchpad.app-name-here")
```

and spits out a nasty error

```
(Daemon.py:26100): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'net.launchpad.app-name-here' is not installed
```

Despite the fact that I can open up dconf-editor and find the settings under net/launchpad/app-name-here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

So I think I may have psuedo-solved my own problem. I copied my schemas from `~/app-name-here/data/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.app-name-here.gschema.xml` to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.app-name-here.gschema.xml` and then compiled my schemas. I'll put the commands to do so below if it can help anyone. (replace app-name-here with the actual name of your quickly app) I believe that this would be done automatically if I had packaged my app into a *deb and then installed it. I believe the problem was that the schemas were not available to all users or the code outside the directory I was workin.

```
$: sudo cp ~/app-name-here/data/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.app-name-here.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
$: sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Answer (score 0):

["quickly run"](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~quickly-committers/quickly/trunk/view/head:/data/templates/ubuntu-application/run.py#L53) adds your ./data/ directory to the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, which lets locally-compiles glib schemas be found by Gio.GSettings.  If you do this in your Daemon.py as well, you will be able to run it from your development directory.